Publicly available website inside a private webapp via docker container
I've got a project that requires an approach I have never done before.
I have an application which can only be access via username/password/mfa. In the application is a section to manage website (CMS) ie. settings, pages, posts etc. Think Wordpress, but not Wordpress.
The public website files are currently within a subfolder of the private application and has its own htaccess, env files etc. When users in the secure CMS make changes to the content, it updates the public website files within the private app area.
I have Docker setup to serve both the private app and the public websites within different containers and ports.
My question is, in the public site, is there any risk in users being able to access files in the private app if the public site is inside a subfolder of the private app?
I've handled virtual hosts with different domains and different folders however never "virtual hosts" within subfolders. Is access limited to the parent virtual host folder only? I know in PHP you can type DIR to get directory or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get document root which would then return the upper parent folder.
I'm also thinking of automated deployment to a separate "parent" folder so the public websites are access outside the secure app however I already have the first approach working and if secure, would leave it as is. I realise security is going to depend on other factors (proper configuration, firewall, headers etc), which I will address, this question is just about the folder structure.
Folder structure is as follows:
app.domain.com
 - public
  - index.php
  - .htaccess
  - public.domain.com
    - public
      - index.php
      - contact.php
      - .htaccess
    - .env
 - src
 - vendor
 - .env
 - ...

For further clarity, each website will have their own domain, own container and host file. They will all be considered separate websites with all their own configuration and credentials.

I actually decided against this approach as the more research I conducted, it didn't give me full confidence directory traversal could not be done.
Instead, I've decided to go with CI/CD from the secure CMS files to the public website folder using Jenkins.
Approach was easier to setup than I thought.

User authenticates
User makes updates to the pages via the secure CMS
On save, webapp triggers a webhook to Jenkins to package the secure CMS files, store them on a shared volume, then send the files to the public folder.

Seems to work OK however if there are any comments or suggestions on how to make it better, I'm open to them.
